# Laravel call function from static function

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Customer Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function tool()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tool');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function createSetting($name, $slug, $classname, $attribute, $value, $customer_id, $priority){
    \App\Setting::create([
        'name' => $name,
        'slug' => $slug,
        'classname' => $classname,
        'attribute' => $attribute,
        'value' => $value,
        'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        'priority' => $priority,
    ]);
}

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($customer)
    {
        $customer_id = $customer->id;
        createSetting('text_primary', 'Primaire tekst kleur', 'dml-pr-text', 'color', 'FFFFFF', $customer_id, 1);
        createSetting('text_primary', 'Primaire tekst kleur', 'dml-pr-text', 'color', 'FFFFFF', $customer_id, 1);
        createSetting('text_primary', 'Primaire tekst kleur', 'dml-pr-text', 'color', 'FFFFFF', $customer_id, 1);
        createSetting('text_primary', 'Primaire tekst kleur', 'dml-pr-text', 'color', 'FFFFFF', $customer_id, 1);
    });

}
}
```

As soon as an new customer is created the static created function is called from where on I try to add a few settings into a database. But the createSetting method from the model is not in the scope of the static function. So I get an error

```
Call to undefined function App\createSetting()
```

How can I make sure the createSetting method can be reached from the static function?

Comment: What about making `createSetting` static as well and call it like so `static::createSetting` ?

Comment: `$this->createSetting` doesn't work?

Comment: Call it as `$customer->createSetting($params)`